# Is it possible to make an app which allows the screen rotation to be locked

Tags: 8.0

I'm wondering if its possible to make apps which make up for setting deficiencies in WP8, specifically, locking the screen rotation.  If it is possible, how much trouble would it be? Is making settings apps particularly difficult? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next update for Windows Phone 8 is GDR3 (or Update 3), which will introduce the ability to lock screen rotation...

http://www.wpcentral.com/microsoft-officially-announces-windows-phone-8-gdr3-update

GDR3 is expected to be released towards the end of this year (2013) [but it's possible to get the **GDR3 Preview** if](http://www.wpcentral.com/download-preview-developers-and-get-gdr3-right-now)...

1. You're a [registered Windows Phone developer](http://dev.windowsphone.com) and have a developer unlocked device.
2. Have signed up to [Microsoft's App Studio](http://apps.windowsstore.com/).